# php cURL undefined index

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm returning values from a retrieved json array. I can parse some data but not others, bellow is a view of the data im trying to pull:

[image]

code:

```
<?php
  $headers = array( //Set headers data
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("Username removed:Password removed") //Set basic authentication
);
  $today = date('Y/m/d');
  $serviceUid='W96397';
  $ch = curl_init('https://api.rtt.io/api/v1/json/service/'.$serviceUid.'/'.$today);//serviceUid is set here
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");            //Set gzip decoding
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);      //not sure
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);   //Set headers in curl options, set previously
  $result=curl_exec($ch);                           //Execute and retrive data
  curl_close($ch);
  $result_arr = json_decode($result, true);

        $serviceUid= $result_arr['serviceUid']; //works fine
        $runningIdentity = $result_arr['runningIdentity']; //works fine

        //All commented out bellow do not return any data*********

        foreach($result_arr['locations'] as $locations){
             $crs = $locations['crs'];
        //   $gbttBookedDeparture = $locations['gettBookedDeparture'];
             $isCall = $locations['isCall'];
             $isPublicCall = $locations['isPublicCall'];
        //   $realtimeDeparture = $locations['realtimeDeparture'];
        //   $realtimeDepartureActual = $locations['realtimeDepartureActual'];
        //   $platform = $locations['platform'];
        //   $platformConfirmed = $locations['platformConfirmed'];
        //   $platformChanged = $locations['platformChanged'];
             $displayAs = $locations['displayAs'];
         }
  ?>
```

Error is: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: platform in /var/www/html/serviceDetails.php on line [line number]

Edit: JSON data: pastebin.com/raw.php?i=P5A7s1Ur

Comment: why don't you say what is ERROR LINE NUMBER? and where is `$anyArr['platform']` call? that line is commented in your code now. so usually `$platform = (isset($locations['platform']))?$locations['platform']:'';`

Comment: every line which is commented out, if uncommeted it throws the error

Comment: Is it possible that one record in the pile is missing this value?

Comment: just checked, no missing data

Comment: by the way you can try `$platform = (property_exists($locations,'platform'))?$locations->platform:'';` because your array elements are Objects, but usually it should work even of you use square brackets. and it is pretty impossible if your data is correct as you show in screenshot and return `$crs=$locations['crs']` but doesn't return `'platform'`. could you provide your data array as a string or file for tests and debug?

Comment: Data Array:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=P5A7s1Ur

Thank you

Comment: check my answer :-) and check your data before use it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to data flile you provide some of elements doesn't include 'platform' property (see examples downhere).

So use techniques I sugessted before:

`$platform = (isset($locations['platform']))?$locations['platform']:'';`

You should verify if property exists before use it.

code:

```
foreach($result_arr['locations'] as $locations){

   $platform = (isset($locations['platform']))?$locations['platform']:'';
   echo '== PLATFORM : '.$platform.' <br />';
}
```

outputs:
`== PLATFORM : 7 
== PLATFORM : 9 
== PLATFORM : 4 
== PLATFORM : 2 
== PLATFORM : 2 
== PLATFORM : 3 
== PLATFORM : 
== PLATFORM : 1 
== PLATFORM : 
== PLATFORM : 2 
== PLATFORM : 2 
== PLATFORM : 
== PLATFORM : 1 
== PLATFORM : 1 
== PLATFORM : 
== PLATFORM : 
== PLATFORM : 
== PLATFORM : 2 
== PLATFORM : 3`

Comment: Thank you, there was so much data I missed a lot of blank arrays which were stopping my program. Thank you.